# is there difference in hosting application within default website and outside default website(as a separate website)

Tags: iis, web-server, iis-7.5, web-hosting, web

I use IIS 7.5

I hosted a web application (windows authenticated) within default Website

server details
server name : kevserver
domain name : kserver-dev.com

I logged in to the server with my creds as shown below

kserver[my username]

Note : my Login domain name is kserver and the servers domain name is kserver-dev.com

when i try to access the Application within the server i am able to access the application.

but if i host the applicaiont as seperate website with host name as fuapp.kserver.com

it throws error stating

"HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied. "

I have host file entry for the website

below are the steps i followed to create the website

- Right click on Sites And select "add website".
- gave FSApp as site name. Selceted app pool. gave the path.
- in binding left Type and Port unaltered selected the servers ip address in the ip section
- gave host name as "fuapp.kserver.com" checked start website immediately.
- then Clicked on OK. 
  Now when i right click on the website and try browse it It asks for credentials. if i give my credentials it is not accepting it
  After three attempts it shows the above said error.

I am unsure if the domain name conflict is the root cause. if so why it didn't occur When i host the application under default website.

Comment: Did you copy all the authentication settings from the Default Site to your New Site? Might be helpful to peruse the web.config in the root of each site.

Comment: yes i did copy all the settings from default site and then removed the default site after creating the new one.